How to display using loop swiper and ngFor
I'm trying to display dynamically slides in my component Angular v.17.1 and SwiperJs v.11.1.
I'm using @for and set loop as true.
my code
I'm getting this error in console and when I'm changing viewport size my images disappear :(
error in console
Has anyone else had the same problem and managed to find a solution?
Regards

related issue https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/7140
